# Broken system after upgrade to Bionic

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I upgraded the usual way and at the end got an error regarding some broken python packages. Possibly because of installing python 3.6 from a ppa. apt-get -f install then an error regarding apt. I manually downloaded and installed libapt from Ubuntu repository for Bionic then updating and apt-get-f install then autoremove.

The system boots, connects to wifi or wired connections but no internet, menus look weird and a blank screen after walking up. Please help.
Update: crda and libcurl4-openssl-dev are broken packages.

```
 cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

$ uname -a
Linux XXX3G 4.15.0-112-generic #113~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 04:37:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please confirm BB version and current kernel, type `cat /etc/os-release` and then `uname -a` and let us know.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: It is safe to try this then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and let us know if you get anything significant in the output.

Comment: It gives an empty output.

Comment: That's a good thing, you probably just have one or two broken packages as you suspected in youe question. Try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` and if nothing breaks then type `sudo apt-get install -f` then reboot.

Comment: But it can't connect to the internet! Even though it connects to networks.

Comment: Try `dpkg --configure --pending` because of course apt assume internet connection.

Comment: Empty output again. Can it be a missing driver?

Comment: Yes you have probably answered your own question. I would post a new question to attract the relevant experts. Title it cannot connect to internet after upgrade to 18.04 or something like that. Then an to the question these outputs `lspci -knn | grep Network -A3` and then `rfkill list` and then `iwconfig` and then `nmcli dev wifi`

Comment: There are some broken packages. See update.

Answer (score 0):

To repair broken packages without an internet connection you'll ned to use another PC and download the deb files [from here](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=crda) and then transfer them to your PC.