# Can't connect to the internet after upgrade to Bionic

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet

This question is a sequel to this one: [Broken system after upgrade to Bionic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274773/broken-system-after-upgrade-to-bionic)

It connects to wired or wireless networks but no internet connectivity.

Pinging ip addresses works but pinging URLs doesn't.
[image: p]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Network-Manager and restart networking.

Comment: No that didn't help.

Comment: Please show output from services --status-all, try to remove broken packages and install again newest versions... download from phone... pkgs.org :)

Comment: I think what clean install is fastest solution, instead of wasting time. Just backup /etc, user profile and reinstall system.

Comment: Apparently there is a DNS problem in Bionic.

Comment: It's easy to check, try to ping Google IP

Comment: If problem with DNS you can also manual setup Open DNS, for example

Comment: Uninstalled the broken packages and now networking is completely disabled. Probably because linux-image-generic was uninstalled too. Believe it or not the bios of the computer has a problem and I can't change boot order to boot from a live disk.